# Appearing <div> should push images below down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an HTML-File.
As you can see, if you click on an image it opens a box below with some text. That works with jQuery. Is there a way to push the images under the box down? 
So that the box never covers an image. Please note that it should be responsive.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/znt3npqa/1/) the fiddle:

That's the css:

```
#projekte {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#projekte li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

#projekte img {cursor: pointer; width: 300px;}

.beschreibung {
    background-color: #bec3c8;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: may be you can change `position: relative;` https://jsfiddle.net/znt3npqa/3/

Comment: As I suspected, fiddling with your fiddle, it's the "position: absolute" that's causing your woes. As it has done to me before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't make the `.beschreibung` elements absolutely positioned, as this will take them out of the flow of the document. Change your css to:

```
.beschreibung {
    background-color: #bec3c8;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znt3npqa/5/) (with vertical-align:top as stated in comments)

Comment: If there's a row of two images, I want to push down only the images below and the two images of the first row stay at their position. And the .beschreibung should be 100% of the viewport width.

Comment: to do that, add `vertical-align: top;` to `projekte li`

Comment: This is working, thank you. Now the only problem is to make the .beschreibung filling the full width of the viewport.

Comment: that requirement is a nasty one.... I dont think you can pull that one off now that these divs are no longer absolutely positioned. Why do you want the text to span the image next to it as well? Doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: It already worked `with vertical-align: top;`, but now it only has to be 100% of the viewport width.

Comment: I meant the 100% width requirement ;)

Comment: Should it be a fully responsive layout? Can there be 3 or even 4 images next to each other?

Comment: Yes, it should be. On normal screen size are 3 or 2 images next to each other.

Comment: I would recommend keeping the old code, but create a new block (that is just the colour of the background) that will also appear, with `position: relative`. The old code will ensure 100% width, but the new block will push the elements down. Make it appear/disappear with the `.beschreibung`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change position parameter to **relative**

```
.beschreibung {
    background-color: #bec3c8;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

And using **jQuery**, you can set it's width, like:

```
jQuery(".beschreibung").width("desired width");
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/znt3npqa/8/)

Also, you need to hide previous image description, like:-

```
$("div[id^='projekt']").hide();
```

Comment: Good point, thanks. But now, if you click on an image in the right column the box goes out of the window.

Comment: @Philipp Then you may have to change your entire html srtucture. I suggest you put a common div for describing 2 images in a single row.

Comment: @Abhi - that would only work when his window is of the size where it fits 2 images in a single row - if you expand that box in fiddle, you can see it can have 3 or more boxes in a row.

Comment: @MichalPaszkiewicz Thats why I have not hardcoded any width value in my answer. FIDDLE is just an example. Dynamic width can be added based on parent width, using **jQuery**

Answer (score 0):

You can change your CSS Class `position: relative`

```
.beschreibung {
    background-color: #bec3c8;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just found an easy solution. I just put the `.beschreibung` in a wrap div and set the `.beschreibung` to 100% width. You can find the updatet fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/znt3npqa/9/